# Access IIS 8 Localhost from internet

Tags: iis, localhost, windows-firewall, windows-8, iis-8

i want access my localhost(IIS 8 On Windows 8) from outside using internet access.

I get my `public ip` from whatismyip.org (202.67.xx.xx) and follow this [link](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/) to open a port(80,443,8081-8082). So i created 3 new rules for port that allowed all program using UTP Protocol in inbound rules on firewall settings.

My Connection : PC -> Modem -> Internet.
My Public IP : 202.67.xx.xx
My IP Get from IPconfig : 10.216.xx.xx

Then i using another computer(laptop) with browser to access my PC public Ip address. I Type in browser 202.67.xx.xx:80 or 202.67.xx.xx:8081 or 202.67.xx.xx:8082, and get result `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 202.67.xx.xx:8081`.

Even i turn off all my firewall, i couldn't connect. I'm Stuck here, can somebody help me please? I'm really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give more details (like error logs of iis). And in ip setting please configure ip address 202.67.xx.xx (needs static ip address).

Comment: You're not going to be able to test outside connectivity from inside your LAN. You're going to have to test it from another connection, but note that most ISPs don't allow you to host web servers on residential/dynamic IPs and it is most likely against the ToS.

Comment: Why are you pretending to be Jeff Atwood?

Comment: @vic it seems my IIS not error, i've tested it in local connection and   it fine. My Ip Address dynamic and i need this solution to test my ASP.NET website in several hours, not for published.

Comment: @jacob how to know? how about using another port? whether there are other ways that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have configured IIS correctly, you will need to do the following:

1. First and foremost - ensure that your **ISP** allows those ports on your internet connection. Most do, but some do not - this is because web hosting is often considered a breach of ToS on domestic internet connections. Ports 8081 and 8082 should be OK, but ports 80 and 443 are sometimes blocked. Your ISP may allow you to unblock the ports.
2. Secondly, you will need to forward those ports to your webserver's **private** IP address. Do this by going to the configuration page on your router titled "port forwarding". From here you will need to specify all the ports you wish to forward. Ensure that you set them to TCP, and that you set the destination address to be your webserver's private IP - this is what you see in ipconfig.
3. Next, ensure that your webserver's firewall (e.g. windows firewall) allows these incoming ports - or simply disable the firewall altogether (not recommended).
4. Lastly, ensure that you test your setup by using a computer that is external to your local network.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but i don't use any router, just my pc connected to GSM modem and then connect to the internet, just it. I've turned off all my firewall(i think rule that i created in inbound connection to be useless). Then i open the browser in another computer with different connection, enter my public IP in there using port 8081 or 8082 and nothing happened, what i miss? thanks

Comment: @CodingHorror   Sorry but you won't be able to do this with a GSM modem. This is because your modem doesn't actually have a public IP Address. The public IP address you're seeing will be on a gateway device owned by your ISP. Your modem (and subsequently your PC) will both have private addresses (Think of it like a LAN network). You NEED some way of instructing the gateway to forward traffic on port 80 to your PC. But unfortunately this is impossible with a GSM modem as the gateway is out of your control.

Comment: In my house, I've ISP that using fiber optic cable. My ISP using modem CISCO model DPC2100r3 that have RJ45 port and fiber optic port(to connect ISP). My ISP is First Media, they provided a modem-router Cisco DPC2100R3 for the internet connection.Can i use it? thanks for your help.

Comment: so what should I have to be able to create a temporary web server at home? thanks

Comment: @CodingHorror Do you have the Cisco modem connected directly to a computer? Or do you have it plugged into a router? If you're using a router then you will have to set up port forwarding as explained in my first post. If it's plugged straight into a PC then you should be good to go - providing you allow the traffic on your windows firewall.

Comment: it's plugged straight into a PC (MODEM -> PC), but  I've read through the internet that any type/kind of modem does not support "PORT FORWARDING". So any solution? thanks

Comment: for information my ISP using Dynamic IP, any solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do port forwarding if the modem is plugged straight into the PC - almost all cable / DSL modems will provide the connected device with a public IP address. Do you get a public IP address on the PC that is connected to the Cisco modem?

Comment: Hey, its worked :), now i can access my local server. Actually, i just access my Apache server not my IIS server, 8081 port for Apache server. I've read from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312136/how-do-i-change-iis-express-8-port-80-to-8080 about change the port of IIS. I change my IIS port to 8080, but when i accessed, nothing happened, Any idea? thanks very much

Comment: I forget create inbound rule for port 8080 in firewall. So my problem solved now. Many Thanks @blacklight PS. Sorry i cannot vote up u'r answer because my reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

its depend upon your ISP provider,most the ISP provider won't allow you to set dynamic ip address for webserver purpose.Beacuse dynamic ip changes thus for testing webpage we need a static address.